# MPAndroidChart, The x-axis line and the grid line overlap?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

so how to render only the x axis and not the grid line on top of that. As can be seen in the picture attached the I've set the width of the axis line to be 4 and the gridline width to be 2 .
So the black line shows up on white axis line. I want to just show the axis line. How do I do that.

[image: the graph plotted]

Answer (score -2):

As it's said in the [docs](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/yaxis/), in order to not draw that gridlines you can try:

`chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false)
 chart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false)`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: If I setDrawGridLines(false) all the gridlines will go .... I don't want , I just want to remove the line which is getting overlapped with my  axis line.